# Inference time varies over different GPUs using Torch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I get a bug when running the below inference code. In the function recognize(), it takes 0.4s to finish prediction. It takes another 3s to return the result `preds_str` to the caller function. I found that if I set `gpu_id=0` in file config, it returns instantly. How can I fix this bug? Thanks in advance.

```
def recognize(imgs, model, demo_loader):

          t = time()
          model.eval()
          with torch.no_grad():
              for image_tensors, image_path_list in demo_loader:
                    batch_size = image_tensors.size(0)
                    image = image_tensors.to(config.device)
                    # For max length prediction
                    length_for_pred = torch.IntTensor([config.batch_max_length] * batch_size).to(config.device)
                    text_for_pred = torch.LongTensor(batch_size, config.batch_max_length + 1).fill_(0).to(config.device)

                    preds = model(image, text_for_pred, is_train=False)
                    _, preds_index = preds.max(2)
                    preds_str = converter.decode(preds_index, length_for_pred)

           print('time elapsed before return:'time()-t) #0.4s
           return preds_str
def main():                        
     model = Model()
     self.model.cuda(config.device)
     model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[config.device], output_device=[config.device]).to(config.device)
     model.load_state_dict(torch.load(config.saved_model, map_location=config.device))
     AlignCollate_demo = AlignCollate(imgH=config.imgH, imgW=config.imgW, keep_ratio_with_pad=config.PAD)
     imgs_dataset = ImageDataset(imgs)
     demo_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(imgs_dataset, batch_size=config.batch_size,shuffle=False,num_workers=int(config.workers),collate_fn=AlignCollate_demo, pin_memory=True)     
     start_time = time()
     # imgs = [img1, img2, ....]
     preds_str = recognize(imgs, model, demo_loader)
     print('time elapsed after return', time()-start_time) #3.4s
```

Config file:

```
    class ConfigWordRecognizer:
        gpu_id = 1 #troublesome line here
        device = torch.device('cuda:{}'.format(gpu_id) if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        imgH = 32
        imgW = 100
        batch_size = 80
        workers = 8
        batch_max_length = 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-switch-model-trained-on-2-gpus-to-1-gpu/20039).
I set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`, `gpu_id=0`. Then, I remove

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[config.device], output_device=[config.device]).to(config.device)
```

and change

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(config.saved_model, map_location=config.device))
```

to

```
model.load_state_dict(self.copyStateDict(torch.load(self.config.saved_model, map_location=self.config.device)))
```

Copy stateDict function:

```
def copyStateDict(self, state_dict):
        if list(state_dict.keys())[0].startswith("module"):
            start_idx = 1
        else:
            start_idx = 0
        new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
        for k, v in state_dict.items():
            name = ".".join(k.split(".")[start_idx:])
            new_state_dict[name] = v
        return new_state_dict
```

The model works well on `gpu1`. But I still don't understand why if I set 'gpu_id=0', it works well on `gpu0` without `copyStateDict`